# If $y'=\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $y(0)=0$, find the value of $y(-2) $

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

If $y'=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ and $y(0)=0$, find the value of $y(-2) = ?$

---

By integrating I am getting
$$y = \ln (x+1)+C$$

I am stuck somewhat as it looks tricky from here. Any help ? Thanks!

Comment: You're almost done. Plug in $x=0$ and $y=0$ and solve for $C$, my friend!

Comment: Ahh thnks! $C=0$ ? but im still not sure how to work $y(-2)$ as it gives $\ln(-1)$

Comment: Since the pole at $x=-1$ separates initial condition and evaluation point, there is no continuous solution connecting both. Thus $y(-2)$ does not exist for a solution of this problem.

Comment: thank you so much, the graph is starting from the right side of -1. Is this answer good : $y(-2)$ is undefined for the solution of IVP because the domain is $x\ge -1$?

Comment: Well, in fact I think the solution should be $\;y=\log|x+1|+C\implies 0=\log|1|+C\implies C=0$ , so we have $$y=\log|x+1|\implies y(-2)=\log|-2+1|=\log|-1|=\log1=0$$

Comment: I thought $|x+1| = x+1$ because $(0, 0)$ is a point on the solution curve... but honestly im really not so sure about these domain stuff

Comment: No, Timbuc is right, when you integrate $1/x$, you get $\log |x|+C$, period. This has nothing to do with the initial conditions of your DE. Of course at the point $x=0$ you have $|x+1|=x+1$, and it's even true for any $x\geq -1$. The point is, it's not true for $x<-1$, and you want to evaluate $y$ at $x=-2$. In short: don't be lazy (though it extremely common): when you integrate $1/x$, never omit the absolute value in the log. However, LutzL is also right, you can't find $y(-2)$ at all.

Comment: Ahh okay so does that mean the solution of IVP is defined for all real $x$ except $x=-2$ ? I am somewhat confused now because Timbuc's reply and  @LutzL 's reply don't seem to agree...

Comment: No, it means that if you have a solution on an interval that includes $0$, then this interval can't be larger than $]-1,+\infty[$. Of course, you could solve the same DE with another initial condition, say, $y(-3)=1$, then you could compute $y(-2)$. But the interval of definition of a solution may not contain $-1$.

Comment: Timbuc is right on the integration, wrong on the conclusion (I didn't pay attention at first). LutzL is right.

Comment: Is this correct answer : $y(−2)$ is undefined for the solution of this IVP because the domain is $x\gt -1$ ?

Comment: Yep, it's right.

Comment: Thats all I need to know. Thank you so much :)